# Storing data in list items

Tags: android, listview

Ultimately, I want to click an item in a ListView (eventually a recycler list view) and have it transfer an id to the next activity for retrieval from the db.

I have a ListView, fed by a CursorAdapter (subclassed). When I set a breakpoint in CursorAdapter.bindView(), the View passed in is of type TwoItemListItem, so I can't set the id on RecipeListItem, which I believe is what I need to do to pass info to the next activity via ListView.setOnItemClickListener().

In the source activity, I get the list view and set the adapter:

```
        RecipeCursorAdapter adapter = new RecipeCursorAdapter(this, cur);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.recipe_list_list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

RecipeCursorAdapter:

```
public class RecipeCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    protected LayoutInflater cursorInflator;

    public RecipeCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor){
        super(context, cursor, 0);
        this.cursorInflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    // The newView method is used to inflate a new view and return it,
    // you don't bind any data to the view at this point.
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent){
        return this.cursorInflator.inflate(R.layout.activity_recipe_list_item, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor){
        // Find fields to populate in inflated template
        TextView tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.recipeListItemTitle);
        TextView tvSubtitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.recipeListItemSubtitle);

        // Extract properties from cursor
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"));
        String description = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("description"));

        // Populate fields with extracted properties
        tvTitle.setText(name);
        tvSubtitle.setText(description);
    }
}
```

activity_recip_list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TwoLineListItem xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:mode="twoLine"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="com.smadacm.reciperepo.RecipeListItem" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recipeListItemTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recipeListItemSubtitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/recipeListItemTitle"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/recipeListItemTitle"
        android:textColor="@color/colorListSecondary"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSecondary" />
</TwoLineListItem>
```

RecipeListItem:

```
public class RecipeListItem extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected int itemId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe_list_item);
    }

    public void setItemId(int id){
        this.itemId = id;
    }
    public int getItemId(){
        return this.itemId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to stumble into something functional. I don't know if this is right, and I'm open to being corrected.

In my main activity, I added a listener:

```
        RecipeCursorAdapter adapter = new RecipeCursorAdapter(this, cur);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.recipe_list_list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                int ii = 0; // A line on which I can set a breakpoint
            }
        });
```

I added a new class to extend LinearLayout. This mostly just calls the super class, but also adds methods to set and retrieve arbitrary data:

```
public class RecipeListItem extends LinearLayout {
    protected int recipeId;

    public RecipeListItem(Context context) {
        super(context, (AttributeSet)null, 0, 0);
    }

    public RecipeListItem(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs, 0, 0);
    }

    public RecipeListItem(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, 0);
    }

    public RecipeListItem(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    public void setRecipeId(int id){
        this.recipeId = id;
    }
    public int getRecipeId(){
        return this.recipeId;
    }
}
```

I used the LinearLayout subclass to define the list items:

```
<com.smadacm.reciperepo.widget.RecipeListItem xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.smadacm.reciperepo.RecipeListItem" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recipeListItemTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recipeListItemSubtitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/recipeListItemTitle"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/recipeListItemTitle"
        android:textColor="@color/colorListSecondary"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSecondary" />
</com.smadacm.reciperepo.widget.RecipeListItem>
```

Finally, in my CursorAdapter, I set the id by item:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View viewRaw, Context context, Cursor cursor){
    RecipeListItem view = (RecipeListItem) viewRaw;
    // Find fields to populate in inflated template
    TextView tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.recipeListItemTitle);
    TextView tvSubtitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.recipeListItemSubtitle);

    // Extract properties from cursor
    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"));
    String description = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("description"));
    int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));

    // Populate fields with extracted properties
    tvTitle.setText(name);
    tvSubtitle.setText(description);

    view.setRecipeId(id);
}
```